# difference between const and function and the meaning of const [A, B] in react native

Tags: react-native, function, use-state, difference

hi everyone i am new to react native. Reading the documentation and seeing various examples, I didn't quite understand a few things:

1. code:

```
const Hello = () => {
    return (
        <div>hello</div>
    )
}
```

and code:

```
Hello() {
     return (
        <div>Hello</div>
    )
}
```

are the same, i.e. do they have the same meaning?and how can I recall them for example when the application starts?

2)and what is the meaning of: `const [A, B] = useState ()`? what do A and B mean?

Comment: I suggest that you read [the fundamentals section of the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/intro-react). Everything that you have asked is covered in this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh , see for first its mostly a Javascript thing. in RN we return JSX

```
const Hello = () => {
    return (
        <div>hello</div>
    )
}
```

stands for `const fun = () => {}`

And this

```
Hello() {
     return (
        <div>Hello</div>
    )
}
```

stands for `function fun() {}`

Thats it.

For point 2 :

```
const [name, setName] = useState ("johndoe") // 0 is default value
```

`useState` is a hook , which is a react feature, here for suppose you want a variable called `name` and you want to display it in your app.

IF you just do `let name = "johndoe"` in react and render it, it will display `john doe`. But if you update its value like `name = "messi"` , in app screen it will still display `john doe` rather than `messi`.

Hence there's `useState` which `rerenders` the screen. So for above

you can update name via `setName("messi")`

and voila you now get `messi` being displayed in app.

i suggest you to follow this [YT article](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNhaISOUy6Q) to understand better

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts